# How to select scratch org in SFDX

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I am new to Salesforce DX and start using VS code and I have created three scratch org while working and now I want to switch between my scratch org, How can I do that?

[image]

example I want to switch to ebikes, what is the command or steps to make sure I am working on correct scratch org?

Thank in advance

Comment: `To specify an org other than the default, use --targetusername`, please refer to the [documentation and commands](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_cli_usernames_orgs.htm)

Answer (score 9):

Specify this as a setting:

```
sfdx force:config:set defaultusername=ebikes
```

You can use either the alias or the full user name (e.g. `test-uqvz0ilj4tje@example.com`).

You must be in a project directory for this to work.

The SFDX command `SFDX: Set a default org` will also work. You can select this from the command palette in VS Code (Ctrl/Cmd+Shift+P).

Comment: SFDX: Set a default org does not work here unfortunately.  This lists authorized sandboxs and production orgs not current scratch orgs.  I have to quit vscode and restart it from the project directory to get it to connect to an scratch org.  I do wish it worked like this though.

Comment: if you set sfdx force:config:set defaultusername=ebikes,  then open the project from vscode it will pickup the correct sandbox.  Thank you!   This is very helpful!

Comment: @muchavie I just tested this and it worked for me. Note that if you create the scratch org from VS Code instead of a terminal, it should also automatically make it default.

Comment: Hum, I create my scratch orgs from build scripts outside of vscode.   I've found that vscode does not show these orgs when I attempt to set then as the default even though they show up in sfdx force:org:list.   Setting the default org from the terminal via sfdx force:config:set does work!   vscode seems to correctly picket of the default from the environment.    This is much better than shutting down and restarting the editor when doing work related to scratch orgs not sandboxes.  I'm satisfied with that!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply a command to a specific org, specify the target username or org alias in the command:

```
sfdx force:source:pull --targetusername test-xxx@example.com
sfdx force:source:push -u xbikes
```

If you want to set the org that all commands default to:

```
sfdx force:config:set defaultusername=ebikes
```

You can get the list of all orgs, usernames and alias' by running:

```
sfdx force:org:list
```

Answer (score -1):

To Set a Scratch Org as default Org (below both ways works for me):

**1. Via VSCode UI:**

1. Ctrl + Shitp + P (OR View > Command Palette)
2. Then type > SFDX: Set a Default Org
3. Select your Stratch name
   eg. stratch1 username: test-qv8z23a21ake@example.com

**2. Via CLI**

```
sfdx force:config:set defaultusername=name-of-stratch
```

FYI: **name-of-stratch** is not username

https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/sf-dev-env/default-org

Comment: This is essentially the same as sfdcfox's answer from ~5 years ago.